# Clr Button, state pressed

Tags: angular, button, vmware-clarity

is there an easy way to change the style of a button? so it looks pressed? I'm using clr-button from clarity project, I have several buttons on the page and my boss wants that the non pressed button to take the style of a secondary button, and the pressed one should look like a primary-button.

These are the buttons:

```
<div id="StatusButtons">
<clr-button-group>
    <clr-button (click)="externalFilterChanged('Upcoming', 'Stipulations')">Upcoming</clr-button>
    <clr-button (click)="externalFilterChanged('Overdue', 'Stipulations')">Overdue</clr-button>
    <clr-button (click)="externalFilterChanged()">All</clr-button>
</clr-button-group>
<clr-button-group>
    <clr-button (click)="externalFilterChanged('PA', 'Type')">PA</clr-button>
    <clr-button (click)="externalFilterChanged('MOA', 'Type')">MOA</clr-button>
    <clr-button (click)="externalFilterChanged('MOU', 'Type')">MOU</clr-button>
    <clr-button (click)="externalFilterChanged('Covenant', 'Type')">Cov</clr-button>
    <clr-button (click)="externalFilterChanged('BSC', 'Type')">BSC</clr-button>
    <clr-button (click)="externalFilterChanged()">All</clr-button>
</clr-button-group>
<clr-button-group>
    <clr-button (click)="externalFilterChanged('Opened', 'Status')">Opended</clr-button>
    <clr-button (click)="externalFilterChanged('Approval', 'Status')">Approval</clr-button>
    <clr-button (click)="externalFilterChanged('Monitoring', 'Status')">Monitoring</clr-button>
    <clr-button (click)="externalFilterChanged('Closed', 'Status')">Closed</clr-button>
    <clr-button (click)="externalFilterChanged()">All</clr-button>
</clr-button-group>
</div>
```

if they were only two I thought perhaps in a boolean to toggle between the `class="btn"` and `class="btn btn-primary"` but since they are several I'm kind of lost.

Here is the link for the buttons from [clarity](https://clarity.design/documentation/buttons), or if there's another way to make it look pressed please tell me, maybe it could work too.

Comment: Did you take a look at the checkbox/radio examples at the bottom of https://clarity.design/documentation/button-group? These are likely what you want if you aren't using a menu overflow.

Comment: @Jeremy Wiljen I'm checking it rigth know, does it have a component like the `clr-button`? or i have to change the code for my `clr-buttons`?

Comment: You don't need a `clr-button` component usually except if you use the overflow feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like below should do the tick:

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn" [class.btn-primary]="true">
       one
    </button>
    <button class="btn" [class.btn-primary]="false">
        two
    </button>
    <button class="btn" [class.btn-primary]="false">
       three
    </button>
</div>
```